# Extract table only from a single page using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract a table in a word document, the following code extracts all the tables, how can I download the table only from one page, let's say page 48

```
from docx.api import Document
import pandas as pd

document = Document("C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/abc.docx")
tables = document.tables
df = pd.DataFrame()

for table in document.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        text = [cell.text for cell in row.cells]
        df = df.append([text], ignore_index=True)

df.columns = ["Column1", "Column2","Column3","Column4","Column5"]
df.to_excel("C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/output.xlsx")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a word document which has text and tables in it. The document is 78 pages big and has several tables in it . I am trying to extract just the tables and specifically the tables which are on page 48-52. I am using the above python code which is extracting all the tables from the word document however i want to only extract tables from a certain date range. Hope it helps.